# jQuery toggle with css properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to toggle between css column layout and a normal layout of a div element with id 'article', but the jQuery is not working... the whole thing just disappears. can anyone tell me how to remove the css properties with jQuery in the toggle function ? I read that you can remove properties like have it below... but it is not working... can anyone please tell me the right way to do it ?

```
function changeview(orientation){
    $('#article').toggle(function(){
       $('#article').css('-webkit-column-width' : '768px', 'height' : '885px');                          
    },function(){                                 
        $('#article').css('-webkit-column-width' : '', 'height' : '');                              
    });
}
```

Comment: don't set CSS properties to empty strings `''`. If you want to set `height` to the default, set it to `auto`. Same with `-webkit-column-width`, although you can use just `column-width` for that and it will work in modern browsers.

Comment: you'd be better off adding/removing classes. Also your syntax is incorrect. Use $('#article').css({'-webkit-column-width':'768px'}); or $('#article').css('-webkit-column-width', '768px');

Comment: Also, for the record, `toggle` is deprecated.

Comment: @MattDiamant what should I use instead of toggle then ?. I tried it with the auto but not working.

Comment: @Derek sorry that I forgot about the {}.

Comment: @CodeWeed There's some good answers below. Try them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the addClass and removeClass for this.

```
<style>
    .newCSS {
        -webkit-column-width : 768px;
        height : 885px;
    }
</style>
```

and the jQuery

```
$('#article').toggleClass("newCSS");
```

Also made a fiddle (simple demo): http://jsfiddle.net/VXmZp/

Comment: what about only `.toggleClass('newCSS');` ?

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ozirij/1/edit)**</kbd>

```
function changeview(orientation){ 
    $('#article').click(function(){    
       var has_H = $(this).height() >= 885 ;         
       $(this).css({
          '-webkit-column-width': has_H ? 'auto' : 768,
                        'height': has_H ? 'auto' : 885
       }); 
    });
}
```

Comment: Wrap the contents of .css in an object `{}` :-)

Answer (score 0):

beat me to it.. always spend too long with my fiddles : http://jsfiddle.net/f64Wy/ 
`toggleClass` as suggested by tymeJV is even better.

update - same example stripped down to use just `toggleClass` - http://jsfiddle.net/f64Wy/1/

Comment: thanks for your answers... I will try it with the toggleClass